# Use curl with default credential

Tags: powershell, curl, credentials

I want to use curl with default credential then I don't need to put my confidential info in the code. Is it possible?

This is how the code is supposed to be:

```
$a = curl UseDefaultCredentials -method POST ....
```

(without entering -u username:password)

Comment: Did you try something and maybe got an error message?

Comment: Yes I try and it returned "Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument"

Answer (score 0):

Prior to PowershellCore v7, curl is an alias for Invoke-WebRequest.

```
Get-Alias -Definition Invoke-WebRequest | 
Format-Table -AutoSize 
# Results
<#

CommandType Name                      Version Source
----------- ----                      ------- ------
Alias       curl -> Invoke-WebRequest               
Alias       iwr -> Invoke-WebRequest                
Alias       wget -> Invoke-WebRequest               
#>
```

PowerShell IVR (aka curl) has a credential parameter.

So, if you want to use real curl.exe then you have to use that extension, otherwise, PowerShell command preference takes over.

> [about_Command_Precedence - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7#:%7E:text=%20About%20Command%20Precedence%20%201%20Short%20description.,that%20has%20the%20same%20name%2C%20PowerShell...%20More%20)
>
> If you do not specify a path, PowerShell uses the following precedence
> order when it runs commands for all items loaded in the current
> session:
>
> Alias Function Cmdlet External executable files (programs and
> non-PowerShell scripts)
>
> Therefore, if you type "help", PowerShell first looks for an alias
> named help, then a function named Help, and finally a cmdlet named
> Help. It runs the first help item that it finds.

So, see the help files on how to use the cmdlet,

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest).Parameters.Keys
# Results
<#
...
Credential
...
#>

Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Examples
# Results
<#
$R = Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://www.bing.com?q=how+many+feet+in+a+mile
$R.AllElements | where {$_.innerhtml -like "*=*"} | Sort { $_.InnerHtml.Length } | Select InnerText -First 5
the shortest HTML value often helps you find the most specific element that matches that text.
$R=Invoke-WebRequest http://www.facebook.com/login.php -SessionVariable fb
$FB
$Form = $R.Forms[0]
$Form | Format-List
$Form.fields
$Form.Fields["email"]="User01@Fabrikam.com"
$R=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://www.facebook.com" + $Form.Action) -WebSession $FB -Method POST -Body $Form.Fields
# Sends a sign-in request by running the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet. The command specifies a value of "fb" for the SessionVariable parameter, and saves 
$R.StatusDescription
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973757(v=vs.85).aspx").Links.Href
#>
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Online
```

or specify the extension and use the command-line options for curl.exe.

As for using credentials security in PowerShell, this is a well-documented thing [all over the web](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20securing%20credentials&form=ANNTH1&refig=ed2c13aefa4f4df7b386160c66c21397&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20securing%20credentials&sc=1-31&qs=n&sk=&cvid=ed2c13aefa4f4df7b386160c66c21397), with several options. There are modules in the MS powershellgallery.com for credential management and use cases.

```
Find-Module -Name '*credential*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results
<#
Version        Name                          Repository Description                                                                                           
-------        ----                          ---------- -----------                                                                                           
2.0            CredentialManager             PSGallery  Provides access to credentials in the Windows Credential Manager                                      
...
1.0.11         pscredentialmanager           PSGallery  This module allows management and automation of Windows cached credentials.                           
...
1.1.7          CredentialStore               PSGallery  CredentialStore saves powershell credentials securely to file                                         
...
1.0.0          CredentialLocker              PSGallery  CredentialLocker is a module that provides commandlets to manage credentials in the password vault....
...
1.1            CredentialsManager            PSGallery  The module Credentials Manager provides you with convenient and safe way to store your credentials ...
...
1.1.0          PSCredentialTools             PSGallery  PSCredentialTools provides various methods for securely storing and retrieving credentials used in ...
...
1.0.477        PSCredentialStore             PSGallery  A simple credential manager to store and reuse multiple credential objects.                           
...
#>
```